# Download file without save dialog

Tags: .net, vb.net

In VB.NET I need to download a file from the web but without the save dialog box appearing. I am using a .net web browser control.

The catch here is I do not know the url of the file that has to be downloaded. It is getting passed by the website.

For example: If I pass the following url in browser "http://www.ncdex.com/MarketDataAction_bhavCopySubmit.action" then webbrowser file download event gets fired and a save file dialog box appears. After this I have to manually click on save and then save the file to a specific path.

I want to automate this process which means file gets saved automatically to the path I want.

Can this be done ? Otherwise I will then have to use sendkeys to manage the dialog box which may not be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using a different class than the WebBrowser control for this particular functionality you can leverage the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class to make this easy:

```
    Dim strURL As String = "http://www.ncdex.com/MarketDataAction_bhavCopySubmit.action"

    Dim strFileLocation As String = "C:\SomeLocation\SomeFileName.SomeExtension"

    Dim objWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(strFileLocation, objWebClient.DownloadData(strURL))
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do it for a url whereby a javascript function once initiated is leading to save dialog box.

Comment: The WebClient class won't execute the Javascript.  if I'm following you correctly, the WebBrowser control navigates to a page and then some JS runs to trigger the download.  Not too sure if you can suppress that functionality in the WebBrowser, but you may be better off just parsing the URL of the file to be downloaded using the WebClient, instead of a WebBrowser.

Comment: Your webclass code works fine if the url passed generates a file for download. However in my scenario when I open a page then a javascript event leads to file save dialog. That works ok with web browser but the save process has to be done manually. In another scenario the date has to be entered then on button click a file download is initiated which I doubt can be done without any manual intervention.

Comment: You can post data using the WebClient class too.  You'll have to analyze the specific information expected to generate the file so you know what data and to what URL to post the data too (if you want it all automatic).

Comment: I open a webpage using webbrowser control then I invoke a script. After that a save file dialog appears. Can this part be automated? As you said the webclient class cannot execute javascript. Second scenario is if a page required date to be filled then button clicked can that also be automated.